# How to get index number inside $.click() of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iteration, selector

```
$("span.ws_label").click(function() {

})
```

By selector "span.ws_label" there are 5 elements selected,

when one of them is clicked,

how to know which one actually?

**EDIT**

I must get the index or its id,$(this) is no use to me.

Comment: To get the id of the element you can call attr("id") on the element
$(this).attr('id') should do it. (Untested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my trick:

```
var i = jQuery(this).prevAll().length;
```

(`i` equals the number of sibling nodes before `this` node)

see: http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prevAll

Comment: Is Query(this) the alias of $(this)?

Comment: 'jQuery' - yes. I always use it to avoid collision with other libraries using $ function.

Comment: @warpech: You could just do `$j = jQuery.nonConflict();` so you won't have to write "jQuery" every time...

Answer (score 1):

Use [JQuery's index function](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index)

```
 $("span.ws_label").index(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(this) inside the function. It's not an index number but it does refer to the element being clicked,